# How many times should SpringJUnit4ClassRunner initialize it's context?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

It is [said in manual](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html), that

> The Test annotation tells JUnit that the public void method to which
>   it is attached can be run as a test case. To run the method, JUnit
>   first constructs a fresh instance of the class then invokes the
>   annotated method. Any exceptions thrown by the test will be reported
>   by JUnit as a failure. If no exceptions are thrown, the test is
>   assumed to have succeeded.

which may mean, that for each `@Test` method the context should be initialized again. This is also confirmed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564309/258483

Simultaneously, I see opposite in my experiment:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringJUnit4ClassRunnerDemo._Config.class)
public class SpringJUnit4ClassRunnerDemo {


    public static class Bean1 {
        {
            System.out.println("Bean1 constructor called");
        }
    }

    public static class Bean2 {

        {
            System.out.println("Bean2 constructor called");
        }

        private Bean1 bean1;

        public Bean1 getBean1() {
            return bean1;
        }

        @Autowired
        public void setBean1(Bean1 bean1) {
            this.bean1 = bean1;

            System.out.println("Bean2.bean1 property set");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class _Config {

        @Bean
        public Bean1 bean1() {
            return new Bean1();
        }

        @Bean
        public Bean2 bean2() {
            return new Bean2();
        }


    }

    @Autowired
    private Bean1 bean1;

    @Autowired
    private Bean2 bean2;


    @Test
    public void testBean1() {

        assertNotNull(bean1);

        System.out.println("testBean1() done");
    }

    @Test
    public void testBean2() {

        assertNotNull(bean2);

        assertSame(bean2.getBean1(), bean1);

        System.out.println("testBean2() done");
    }


}
```

This code outputs

```
Bean1 constructor called
Bean2 constructor called
Bean2.bean1 property set
testBean1() done
testBean2() done
```

which may mean, that context is not initialized second time before second test.

What is actual and correct behavior and how to control it?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong and you are reading the wrong documentation. The Spring Test Context framework is taking care of loading the context only once, this for performance reasons as it is generally quite time consuming to load the context. If you really want to reload the context add `@DirtiesContext` to your test methods or test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the Spring context reloaded between test methods, you need to use the `@DirtiesContext` annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html